# Find $T^*$ such that $\langle Tx,x \rangle \geq 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

let $H$ be hilbert space and let $T:H \to H$ be a linear operator . we assume that $\langle Tx,x \rangle \geq 0$ $\forall x\in H$. 
Find $T^*$ and $Im(T)$.
By difinition of $T^*$  we must have
$$(Tx,y) = (x, T^*y), \qquad x, y \in H$$
But we don't know the expression of $T(x)$ 
Anyways  I think  we should put $\lambda =(Tx,x) $ such that $\lambda \geq 0$ 
Thanks to anyone who tries to help me.

Comment: Hint: try to show $T=T^*$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace   thank you

Comment: @QuantumSpace  My attempt $(Tx,x)\in\mathbb{R}$ then $ (Tx,x)= \overline{(Tx,x)}= (x,Tx)$ is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, $(Tx,x) = (x,Tx) = (T^*x,x)$ for all $x$ which implies $T = T^*$ (do you know why? Hint: polarisation identity).

Comment: @QuantumSpace I do . Thank you very much  I appreciate it

Comment: You are very welcome. Also, welcome to MSE!

Comment: @QuantumSpace: I think it should be mentioned that $H$ has to be a *complex* Hilbert space, as your hint of the polarization identity suggests and a rotation matrix in $\mathbb{R}^2$ confirms.

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, you are right. The implication $\langle Tx,x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$ implies $T=0$ fails when the field is real. I'm biased because I always work with complex vector spaces :)